# How to combine the multiple days of a dose for meta analysis

Tags: meta-analysis, case-control-study

I want to do a meta-analysis on case-control animal studies. But the problems is, a dose contain multiple days and shows their effects at each day like after 7, 14, 28 days. In a meta-analysis, I show they the combined data into three part while the main study contain 6 type of duration. How can do this type of meta analysis with different duration time of same dose?